# C++ ctors: What's the point of using initializer list in a .cpp file?

Tags: c++, performance

C++ has this funky quirk of supporting initializer lists for a ctor, such as:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(int x) : m_x(x) { }
private:
  SomeComplexObjectThatTakesAnIntForConstruction m_x;
}
```

Makes sense so far.  More efficient because the member is only initialized once, rather than being default-constructed, and then operator= assigned a value later.

But I commonly come across programmers who put the ctor in their .cpp file, where I can hardly believe it actually has the intended (efficient) effect of actually using the initializer list correctly:

```
// Foo.cpp
Foo::Foo(int x) : m_x(x)
{
  // complex set of things needed to be done, or perhaps dependency-inducing references here...
}
```

As I understand things, the above won't necessarily generate a single construction for m_x, because the initializer-list is not visible outside of this translation unit, and will result in construction + assignment, no?

```
// user.cpp
Foo my_foo(9);  // how can the ctor for m_x be effectively inlined here?
```

Or have I misunderstood how initializer-lists function?

Thanks for your help with this ;)

---

I have chosen to split the initializer-list and body of the construction into two pieces, such as:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(int x) : m_x(x) { Initialize(); }
private:
  void Initialize(); // defined in our .cpp thus isolating dependencies and creating a common call-point for multiple ctors (if present)
  SomeComplexObjectThatTakesAnIntForConstruction m_x;
}
```

Comment: If a ctor is implemented, what difference does it make where?

Comment: initializer lists and inlining are 2 different things. What makes you think initializer lists need to be inlined to work correctly?

Comment: I'm not saying they don't work - I'm questioning their efficiency.

Comment: Good luck using the pimpl idiom.

Comment: Actually, this "question" might actually be useful.  It exhibits, quite obviously, exactly what is behind all attempts to gain "efficiency" before testing: ignorance.  This person doesn't understand constructors and has decided on a path of policy that is going to severely limit them in the future all in the name of "efficiency" that they'll never gain.  Perfect example of pre-optimization fail.

Comment: This reminds me of the controversy/debate about the different template models.  I.E. Borland compilers had to see template code in a header file in order to function.  IBM C++ and, I think, GCC among others used a collect stage in the linker to collect all template instatiations and remove dups so there was only one instance of the code for each instantiation.  For example, say you have 10 classes that all use vector<int>.  Borland would instantiate it as many times as it appeared in a header, bloating the code.  The collect based compilers would throw away the exact duplicates at link time.

Comment: @Noah - I have used the pimpl pattern any number of times, and have never found the above to have any bearing whatsoever, positive or negative, on the pimpl idiom.  Yes, I agree that my understanding is limited - that is the point of asking a question.  And would you like to explain in what way that this limits or excludes any optimization whatsoever?

Comment: Obviously you don't know what the pimpl idiom is either.

Comment: @Noah - stop being an ass and try to be of some use to the question at hand, or go bung yourself.

Comment: @JimR - it's good to hear that some compilers at least do a collection stage, and would be able to "see through" to the implementation.  I guess I still have the impression that this is much like relying upon the compiler to optimize away things that might or might not actually happen, such as MyObj x(5) vs. x = 5;

Comment: @Mordachai - There's no difference at all short of the second being disallowed when the constructor's explicit.  The pimpl idiom uses a named but as of yet undefined type and so is utterly incompatible with the constructor definition being in the header; and that's just one case.  You've been told several times that you don't understand but keep insisting.  Who's being the ass?  You've much to learn before you start trying to optimize your code before you even write it.

Comment: @Noah - your arrogance is astounding, and embarrassing.  Even if I have totally misunderstood this particular aspect of C++, then it serves as a useful bit of insight for others who may likewise misunderstand it.  The point of answering questions is not to show your superiority, but to assist others who are confused or befuddled by some aspect of programming.  Insulting a person for their lack of understanding is just obnoxious.  Failing to listen further, and get to the bottom of what's confusing is your failure.  And you rob yourself the chance to discover things you didn't already know.

Comment: @Noah: I often find your answers enlightening, but, sometimes you turn into the arrogant little turd that everyone loves to hate.  I think this is one of those cases.  Please stop.

Comment: The worst thing about inlining is that when you use it in a library it breaks binary compatibility unless it is safe to call the old implementation in the new version of a library. So people defining constructors in the CPP file are probably doing the right thing.

Comment: http://crazyeddiecpp.blogspot.com/2010/12/inline-functions-and-you.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have misunderstood.

The initializer list doesn't need to be visible from other translation units the same way that the constructor body doesn't need to be visible from other translation units.  It affects the code which is generated *for* the constructor itself, not the code which is generated to *call* the constructor.

---

Maybe this will clear up the confusion:

Inlining is one particular optimization.  It is not the only type of optimization possible.  Modern C++ compilers are capable of performing all sorts of other optimizations (loop unrolling, reordering of statements when they don't affect the program's behavior, etc).

The "short cut" or "efficiency gain" that inlining gives you is the elimination of the need to create a new frame on the call stack.  Typically, the code generated for a function call looks something like this, where lines prefixed by `--` are part of the called function (assuming the C calling convention).

```
Push the arguments on to the stack
Push the current code address onto the stack
Jump to the address of the function
-- Move the stack pointer forward to create space for local variables
-- Execute the body of the function
-- Move the stack pointer back to remove the local variables
-- Pop the caller's address from the stack and jump to it
Pop the arguments from the stack
```

If the function is inlined, this becomes just the first three steps performed by the called function:

```
-- Move the stack pointer forward to create space for local variables
-- Execute the body of the function
-- Move the stack pointer back to remove the local variables
```

This optimization relies on the ability of the compiler and/or linker to change *where* code is generated, not *what* code is generated.

In contrast, the initializer list affects *what* code is generated, not *where* it is generated.  The compiler can still generate calls to non-default constructors for member variables whether it is doing it directly at the call site or in a separate section of of the program code that the call will jump to.

Comment: But by definition no inlining or short-cuts can be obtained by the compiler when the function-definition is not available to the caller's scope...

Comment: Modern compilers are a lot smarter than you're making them out to be.

Comment: @Mordachai, please see my edits.  You are correct that inlining cannot occur when the function definition is not available to the caller.  However you are wrong to assume that means no other optimizations are possible in that situation either.  I hope that the edits clarify how inlining is different in that regard.

Comment: I didn't down-vote anyone!  Thanks Nick, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Because of this statement: "... this type of optimization really does require that the compiler know the body of the function at the point where it is called."  It's not only false, it's exactly the kind of thing that makes people go through all these hoops to "optimize" their code.  There's a great variety of optimizations that can happen at *link* time, INCLUDING inlining.  Good compiler suites are very adept at it.

Comment: +1: This is the answer I would have written if I was a decent writer. :)

Comment: @Mordachai: @Nick Meyer: Not true. @Noah Roberts is correct. The compiler is capable of inlineing even if the source is not visible at the point of usage. It is part of inter compilation unit optimization (Now it is true that this is non trivial and your basic compilers don't bother) but good compilers (like gcc/cc1) are quite capable of doing it. Eg. `g++ a.c b.c` Here the source of a.c is not visible in b.c (vice versa) but the compiler has enough information to perform inlining of the code in both compilation units. You can see dev-studio trying to take advantage of this (look at logs).

Comment: @Noah @Martin, you are correct; I overlooked link-time optimizations.  At any rate, I hope the example cleared up the OP's confusion.

Comment: @Noah @Martin, I've reworded the statement you objected to.  I hope this is a more accurate representation.

Comment: @Noah Thanks for the bologspot post - it's very clear and helpful.

Comment: @Noah: @Nick Meyer: @Noah Roberts: I would not call it a link time optimization. It is usually done when the compiler is translated the source into its own internal representation (but before it emits assembly). The internal representation is usually a directed a-cycle graph. It is relatively simple to graft a graph into the location of a single graph node that represents a call as the inputs/outputs of the spliced graph should match the inputs/outputs of the call node.

Answer (score 9):

Initializer lists work fine when implemented in .cpp files - what makes you believe they wouldn't?

An initializer list is still part of the constructor 'call'.  It's just a syntax that formalizes how construction of class members will take place (note for novices - it doesn't direct or influence the *order* of class member construction, but it allows parameters to be passed to the member's constructors). This makes possible the simple rule that when the first statement after the opening brace is reached, all class members have been through their construction, but it doesn't mean that the initializer list needs to occur before the constructor is called.

---

To address Mordachai's comment:

Having the init list in the header vs. in the .cpp file would affect the 'inline-ability' of the constructor (or the initialization list, if you're deferring the main work of the constructor to a function call in the inlined ctor). However, that's true of any in-header implementation of a member function vs. an implementation in a .cpp file.

I suspect that for most ctors, performance concerns will be due to resource allocation -if they aren't acquiring a resource, they're probably not going to have perf issues - and that's going to take the same amount of time whether the ctor is inlined or not.  Note that this still means that init lists are important, whether they're inlined or not, because they prevent the situation (that you mentioned in your question) where:

- a member object is default initialized (possibly acquiring a resource in an expensive operation)
- re-initializing the member object (which may result in releasing the resource, then acquiring a new resource)

Since resource acquisition/release is typically expensive (whether that resource is memory, a network connection, opening a file) compared to many other things, this is an important anti-pattern to avoid. However, the performance difference between whether these resource acquisitions are inlined or not is probably not significant in most cases, I'd think.

Of course, there are also correctness issues that are addressed by the initialization list.  For example, since `const` members can't be modified, they must be initialized in an initialization list.

Comment: I know that this must work.  Obviously the compiler has to handle this or it would be outlawed by the language.  However - just in the same way that a function must result in a function call unless the source for that function is visible at the call site, wouldn't the exact same be true for initializer lists in ctors? Wouldn't the compiler be forced to first allocate the stack, then call the ctor vs. inlining the entire construction process (sans any function calls it makes itself).

Comment: @Michael Burr: You say: *it doesn't direct or influence the order of class member construction, but it allows parameters to be passed to the member's constructors*. If this is true, why do some C++ compilers still warn if your initializer list is not in the same order as the variables are declared in the class definition?

Comment: @JimR: I wish all C++ compilers would warn about that (in fact, I wish it was an error). The reason they warn is exactly *because* the init list doesn't determine init-order, but it reads like it does. Even experienced programmers who know this (at least me) can still be tricked because you don't typically have a member declaration order memorized, and reading the init list leads you to believe something that may not be true. Most of the time it's not important, but sometimes there are dependencies between member object initialization that matter.

Comment: Mordachai: I've tried to address the issue raised in your comment more completely (I think) in an edit to the answer.

Comment: @Michael Burr: In the early 90s when Borland first came out with their OS/2 C++ compiler there was a HUGE performance penalty with their compiler for out of order initialization via the initializer list.  I think it was either Nathan Myers or Frank Griswold from Rogue Wave that found this issue.  I'm not sure Borland every corrected it... :)

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciated everyone's effort.  I think at this point I need to worry not at all about placing initializer-lists in .cpp or .h. ;)

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of the initializer-list is not simply a matter of efficiency.

Aside from the cases where a member must be initialized there because there is no way to do otherwise (references, const-members, class members with no default constructor), it is generally "preferred" in the same way you initialise variables when you first declare them.

There are occasions where it is better to use the constructor body to set variables to their correct values, for example if you have two pointers that will point to objects created with new, and you are scared the second new may throw. In this case you should still "initialize" them - to NULL - then create them in the body, the first one inside an auto_ptr just in case (which you release after the second one works).

The purpose of moving the constructor body into the compilation unit is to hide the implementation detail from the interface. This is generally preferred for maintainability which a lot of time is hugely more important than a minor amount of runtime efficiency that saves microseconds.

Comment: I agree that there are other implications - and you've given good reasons why initializer-lists are sometimes necessary, and reasons why they're sometimes a sub-optimal choice (using multiple raw new's - which is generally a bad idea from an exception-safety perspective).  My point is don't you guarantee to have temp objects constructed and moved up & down the ctor chain when the ultimate use of a given element can't be seen at the invocation site?

Comment: You should be using smart pointers for members too and then the necessity to initialize them in the body is gone.  Exceptions thrown by later initializations will result in destruction of previous ones.

Comment: @Mordachai: That is a separate question. As CashCow and Nick Meyer indicate, the primary goal of initializer lists doesn't have anything to do with inlining.

Comment: @CashCow: @Mordachai: If you obey the rule that an object should only manage 1 resource then your only issue becomes a non issue. As all your pointers are replaced by smart pointers that will behave correctly even in the face of exceptions. Also You can place a try catch block around the initializer list for the rare cases where it is a problem. The only thing in the function body should be processing of inputs **ALL** members can and should (with a few obscure exceptions) should be done in the initializer list.

Comment: @Noah You do not have to always use smart pointers, there are good reasons to sometimes use raw pointers especially as RAII is preserved anyway if your destructor deletes them. The main one of these is that apart from shared_ptr most smart pointers do not work with forward declarations. @Martin You should not put try..catch around the initialiser list just to preserve exception safety, it will be difficult to know what to put in catch anyway, better to use the body and auto_ptr as a temporary measure.

Comment: @CashCow - actually, you described above exactly why RAII is broken when you don't store member pointers in smart pointers.  I've never run into a smart pointer that doesn't work with forward declarations.  Of course, you can't create or destroy one until you have a full declaration, but that's the way pointers work; it's no different at all (except you'll actually get a compiler error if you forget to create your destructor).  The shared_ptr construct only works because it builds a deleter upon creation so it can be destroyed without knowing what it is; IT is the special one.

Comment: When I say it works with forward declarations I mean you can store SomeSmartPtr<T> in your header with a forwardly-declared T and users of your class will not need to include the header for T, particularly as it is private and therefore none of their business. You can use shared_ptr to achieve this and many do but it has a big overhead and effectively you're using the wrong smart pointer just to achieve this goal. Even if you implement the destructor in the source file, not all compilers allow the forward declaration with scoped_ptr or auto_ptr.

Answer (score 0):

I think initializer lists are there not for efficiency, but for semantics.

For one, they are a chance to initialize members before the superclass's constructor gets called, which could call virtual member functions, coming back invisibly into the lower-level class, before the lower-level constructor had finished.

For another, they are a way of guaranteeing that certain fields are initialized to non-garbage values, unlike assignment statements inside the constructor code that swim in a syntax of if-statements, loops, etc, that the compiler can't be sure will get executed.

For another, it lets you declare the class as const while still allowing you to initialize it. (But I'm not positive about than one.)

Comment: `virtual` methods don't descend to derived classes when called from a constructor.  See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.5